# PHP Curl - Is it possible to evade Cloudflare block?

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

We have recently encountered CloudFare blocking on some sites we have not had issue scraping in the past.

It is not an IP block (tried from several IPs) and it is not tied to an account or any other kind of authentication. The site does not show user captchas

We created a PHP Curl request using the exact `GET` request with all headers but we receive a `403 Forbidden` error and it displays:

```
www.******.com used CloudFlare to restrict access
```

Forgive my ignorance, but how does CloudFlare detect this? There are no cookies involved (as its the initial site request), the user-agent and everything else is identical.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.******.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Host: www.******.com';
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Ch-Ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1';
$headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

result

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Any possible workaround?

Thank you

Comment: This is the issue of copying other peoples data, they sometimes come up with a way of making it difficult.  If you contact the web sites they may be able to help you.

Comment: "Forgive my ignorance, but how does CloudFlare detect this?" A variety of ways, some involving JavaScript (including testing for specific JS handling edge cases in the type of browser your user agent pretends to be). The workaround is to reach out to the site in question and ask for an API.

Answer (score 0):

i think only cloudflare developers can give you correct answer.  But they will not open their commercial secrets so easily.
All other information is theories and speculation. as far as i know, as response to first request to site cloudflare shows page with some javascript to profile browser, to proof it is stack browser used by humans, not curl.
if browser is stack one, than cloudflare allows requests to be served by backend.

I think you can try selenium, sometimes it doesn't trigger cloudflare blocker page with captcha